# Enable mass storage and ethernet over USB or a terminal device function over USB in Kubos Linux

Tags: linux, embedded, vagrant, usb, beagleboneblack

I've been trying to emulate the ethernet over USB functional or a terminal device over USB function in Kubos Linux (https://docs.kubos.com/1.21.0/index.html).

The version of linux kernel is 4.4.23. The Kubos Linux is deployed on beaglebone black and uses uboot to boot the linux. I have enabled CONFIG_USB_NET_DRIVERS in the linux-kubos.config which you can see here: https://github.com/kubos/kubos-linux-build/blob/master/board/kubos/beaglebone-black/linux-kubos.config. After this I compiled the linux and created a kubos-linux.img and aux-sd.img and flashed the SD card. I booted the board from SD card however, I still could not see the ethernet over USB emulation after the flash.

I use buildroot for compiling and building the kubos kernel and aux image in the vagrant VM in virtual box.

I wanted to know if I am missing some key information to add these functionalities and if there were any beaglebone black specific driver configuration I need to enable in kubos linux kernel?

At the moment, I use an FTDI cable to communicate with the board serially using minicom however, this is very slow and want to use ethernet over USB or terminal functionality to make this communication faster.

Comment: Does log show discovery of your Ethernet adapter? What about lsusb?

Comment: @stark currently, busybox is used for executing system commands like lsusb. However, dmesg has not been added to busybox yet to check for kernel logs. Is there some other way I can check the logs for the networking adapters?  The output of ***lsusb*** is ***Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002*** After flashing Kubos img and booting it from SD card, I don't see the beaglebone as a mass storage device or a networking device over usb both on my local machine and the Vagrant VM.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to make the Beaglebone look like an ethernet peripheral.  See, for example,  https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_configure_the_Linux_kernel/drivers/usb/gadget

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I saw that there quite a few config options I could possibly set to enable the drivers, I will try it out. I'm not sure what ethernet peripheral means exactly but I want to add ethernet over USB so I can SSH into the beaglebone over USB and do file transfers. For instance, the way I can SSH into the the Debian on board over USB, when I first used beaglebone right out of the box.